# vue new project: npm ERR! missing script: serve

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am getting `npm ERR! missing script: serve` when I try to build my project in vue.js to serve it at localhost. My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "obz-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed not contain a script named `serve`, or the `scripts` object at all, so it's unclear why you expected any different.

Comment: what does "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0" denote

Comment: The version of that plugin that your package relies on in the development environment. You should probably look for some kind of introductory tutorial.

Comment: i have the exact same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572705/vue-cli-doesnt-make-anything-i-can-serve/60572728#60572728  did you ever get this resolved?  @user2949393