# vue cli doesn't make anything i can serve

Tags: vue.js

Running inside a node:12 development container

```
  Successfully created project pullervue.
  Get started with the following commands:

 $ cd pullervue
 $ npm run serve
```

I follow the commands:

```
root@2f2f88bce6d9:/workspace# cd pullervue/
root@2f2f88bce6d9:/workspace/pullervue# npm run serve
npm ERR! missing script: serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-06T22_55_06_888Z-debug.log
```

i notice no real files?

```
root@2f2f88bce6d9:/workspace/pullervue# ls   
README.md  package-lock.json  package.json
```

package.json:

```
root@2f2f88bce6d9:/workspace/pullervue# more package.json 
{
  "name": "pullervue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0"
  }
}
```

cli version:

```
root@2f2f88bce6d9:/workspace/pullervue# vue --version
@vue/cli 4.2.3
```

i tried several times with different configurations, just trying with default here.

Comment: can you check this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572208/vuex-photourl-and-displayname-have-been-passed-null-to-setuser

Answer (score 0):

i am not really sure how this got fixed, but i removed some environment variables and volumes in my docker-compose.yml file...

somewhere along the line it got confused somehow, its working now